# Transmute list of dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas

Attempting to track rank over time for various apps:

```
# I need to convert this list of dicts: 

[{"Date" : "7/1/16", "Foo": 32, "Bar" : 49, 'Spam': 55},
{"Date" : "7/2/16", "Foo": 43, "Bar" : 44, 'Spam': 77},
{"Date" : "7/3/16", "Foo": 23, "Bar" : 47, 'Spam': 63}]

# Into this list of dicts:

[{"AppTitle" : "Foo", "7/1/16" : 32, "7/2/16" : 43, "7/3/16" : 23},
{"AppTitle" : "Bar", "7/1/16" : 49, "7/2/16" : 44, "7/3/16" : 47},
{"AppTitle" : "Spam", "7/1/16" : 55, "7/2/16" : 77, "7/3/16" : 63}]
```

Essentially, I need to create a dataframe that will work with a wrapper
I built for python's CSV module. I looked through tons of questions relating to creating dataframes from lists of dicts, but nothing quite fit my need.

For reference: Foo, Bar, & Spam are App titles,
and the number is the rank for the specified date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([{"Date" : "7/1/16", "Foo": 32, "Bar" : 49, 'Spam': 55},
                   {"Date" : "7/2/16", "Foo": 43, "Bar" : 44, 'Spam': 77},
                   {"Date" : "7/3/16", "Foo": 23, "Bar" : 47, 'Spam': 63}])
```

From this DataFrame, you can get your result using the transpose method:

```
df.set_index('Date').T.reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'AppTitle'}).to_dict('r')
Out: 
[{'7/1/16': 49, '7/2/16': 44, '7/3/16': 47, 'AppTitle': 'Bar'},
 {'7/1/16': 32, '7/2/16': 43, '7/3/16': 23, 'AppTitle': 'Foo'},
 {'7/1/16': 55, '7/2/16': 77, '7/3/16': 63, 'AppTitle': 'Spam'}]
```

Comment: what do I need to import here? is it just `import pandas as pd`?

Comment: @BenjaminJames: Please keep in mind that pandas is not part of Python's built-in standard modules and might depend on numpy (which I am not totally sure about).

Comment: @albert I assumed he was familiar with pandas because he talks about dataframes in the question.

Comment: @albert The OP listed the python and pandas tags below his question indicating it's a pandas question

Comment: @ayhan right, i have pandas+numpy. thanks for the answer.

Comment: @JoeR actually someone edited my question and put the pandas tag on